# Writing vector * matrix * vector

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I am using `$\vec{s}^\intercal \vec{A} \vec{s}$` to represent s^T * s * S where s is a column vector and A is a square matrix. The problem with this representation is that there is little too much space between s^T and As.

Is there a way I can represent this with uniform spacing?

PS: I am using `\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may depend on personal preference, but you could increase of decrease the horizontal gap between your vectors/matrices:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\begin{document}
$\vec{s}^\intercal\!\vec{A} \vec{s}$ \quad
$\vec{s}^\intercal \vec{A}\mskip\thinmuskip \vec{s}$
\end{document}
```

The first example adds a negative `\thinmuskip` to draw `A` closer to `s^T`, while the second example reverses this process, pushing `s` `\thinmuskip` away from `A`.

Perhaps, in this instance, in may be advisable to produce a command that could do this spacing for you, rather than fiddle with the spacing every time (for consistency):

```
\newcommand{\vmprod}[3]{%
   \vec{#1}^\intercal\!\vec{#2}\vec{#3}%
}
```

Now you would be able to use `$\vmprod{s}{A}{s}$` and obtain the spacing provided in the first example.

You could go one step further. If your structure is very similar and usually has the form `s^T A s`, you could structure the command to take only two arguments, with an optional third using [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\vmprod}{o m m}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {\vec{#3}^\intercal}% \vmprod{A}{s}
    {\vec{#1}^\intercal}% \vmprod[t]{A}{s}
  \!\vec{#2}\vec{#3}%
}
\begin{document}
$\vmprod{A}{s}$ \quad
$\vmprod[x]{A}{y}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: this works only if `#2` is "A" -- it's the relative shapes of "A" and `\intercal` that result in the gap.

Answer (score 8):

Tex automatically inserts a space `\scriptspace` (0.5pt) after every sub or superscript.  Define a command to get rid of it

```
\newcommand\transp{^\intercal\kern-\scriptspace}
```

and then use it

```
$\vec{s}\transp \vec{A} \vec{s}$
```

Some letters may need additional kerning, compare

[image]